Angular changes URL, but doesn't open child
I'm getting strange behaviour.
My parent URL has this.
ProjectsComponent HTML snippet
 <a [routerLink]="[contract._id]">{{ contract.name }}</a>

Scenario 1
When I navigate to the parent from another component, and then click on the above link, in the parent, the URL changes, but the child does not load.
Scenario 2
However, when I refresh the browser so that I land straight to this parent componeng (not navigating to it from another component), then the child component does load.
Here is the routing set up
    {
            path: 'contracts',
            title: 'App | Contracts ',
            component: ProjectsComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: ':id',
                component: ModalContainerComponent, // --> does not load in scenario 1
                children: [
                  { path: '', redirectTo: 'view/personal', pathMatch: 'full' },
                  { path: 'view/personal', component: PersonalInformationComponent},
                ] 
              }
     }


I've worked out the root cause, and reported it as a bug to the Angular team:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/55305
